# Disable Order item link

Tags: woocommerce

Limit User Access

I'm trying to limit user access to not let him edit product data, such as weight, price, measurements...

I installed the Ultimate Dashboard Plugin and even managed to remove this direct access, letting him see only the orders page, because that's what I want him to have access to.

But when you open the order, he can still access the product through the order link.

Please is there any way I can disable this possibility?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using the [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) plugin. You can create a custom role there and uncheck the "Edit Product" capability.

Once you created the new custom role, you should go to the "All Users" page from the left admin sidebar, then find the user that you want to prevent editing the products and change its role to the new role that you created with the plugin.

Here is the documentation and examples:
http://shinephp.com/user-role-editor-wordpress-plugin/